# create loop for iterating linear regression in python

Tags: python, loops, regression

I am new in python and i want to create a loop for multiple regression to see how the error are reducing. This is a very simple exmple but I could not include the loop in the code and it gives me indentation error. How i should fix it?

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error             

max_r = 10

# Load the dataset using 10 features 
X, y = load_housing_data(n=10)
  
# Vector for storing the training error for each r
linreg_error = np.zeros(max_r)    

### STUDENT TASK ###
# Loop max_r times:
#  reg = ...
#  reg.xxx(...)
#  y_pred = ...
#  linreg_error[...] = ... 

# YOUR CODE HERE
for r in range(max_r):
reg = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True) 
reg.fit(X[:,0:r], y)
y_pred = reg.predict([:,0:r])
training_error = mean_squared_error(y, y_pred)

linreg_error[r]=training_error
print(linreg_error)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you get an indentation error and the code is exactly the same as the one you posted here, it's just because in python the body of a for loop must be indented. So the four lines following your `for` statement must begin with a `tab`.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says you have an indentation error, Pyton is a very exquisite language with indentations.

Python uses four spaces as default indentation, so your code should look like this:

```
for r in range(max_r):
    reg = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True) 
    reg.fit(X[:,0:r], y)
    y_pred = reg.predict([:,0:r])
    training_error = mean_squared_error(y, y_pred)
    linreg_error[r]=training_error
```

Comment: Note that the number of space doesn't matter. Any indent is fine, as long as the whole block is consistently indented